# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib | Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

`Flutter Channel: Stable`
`Flutter Version: v2.5.0`

App Crashes after launching on iOS Simulator...
Works fine on Android Emulator...

VS Code Output:

```sh
Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

XCode 13 (Beta) Output:

```sh
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/usamasarwar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/858AC3A7-2F5B-42A0-8710-8AF64C414CD9/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5C683483-287D-470E-B53E-0C9A1D1D9306/Runner.app/Frameworks/audio_manager.framework/audio_manager
  Reason: image not found
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR=/Users/usamasarwar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld/20G95/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0.18A394
DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/usamasarwar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-enixqgwcsocuxscmnmxjnursmjtq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 14.0.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib:/Library/Developer
(lldb)
```

Comment: Does it run from Xcode? Ran into something similar, and VScode doesn't launch an iOS simulator on M1, it just times out. However if a simulator is already running, you can select it from the available devices. Can you confirm?

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad >> This error was generated by VS Code. iOS Simulator was already running, I just selected and run the program.

The app is running fine on Android but not on iOS, It launches and crashes...